# floating a list within a div

Tags: css, css-float

I want to do a collapsible button that opens a list of items when clicked, I'm trying to float the elements left within the button but it's not seem to be working.

```css
.collapsible-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsible-content {
  float: left;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.collapsible {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 33%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: Transparent;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-group">
  <button class="collapsible">Modern Trade</button>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <ul>
      <li>num 1</li>
      <li>num2</li>
      <li>num3</li>
      <li>num4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
<div class="collapsible-content">
  <ul class=my-float"> <li>num 1</li>
  <li>num2</li>
  <li>num3</li>
  <li>num4</li></ul>
```

// in your css file add this

```
.my-float li{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: @OdayBanihani hello  did u add  the css  as  i said ?

Comment: try this  ul li { float:left !important ;}

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript to detect the button click and then do something with it. This code adds a class to the div containing the menu and changes the maximum height.

```js
const myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
myButton.onclick = () => {
  const menu = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-content")[0];
  menu.classList.toggle("showMenu");
}
```

```css
.collapsible-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsible-content {
  float: left;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.collapsible-content.showMenu {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.collapsible {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 33%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: Transparent;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-group">
  <button class="collapsible">Modern Trade</button>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <ul>
      <li>num 1</li>
      <li>num 2</li>
      <li>num 3</li>
      <li>num 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```